# HRESULT 0x80070005 from D3DCompile

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

I'm trying to write my first program that uses DirectX in C++. I'm trying to use it to run calculations to update a buffer that will be drawn to the screen. Here is my current code:

```
    // Create Direct3D 11 device and context
    ID3D11Device* device = nullptr;
    ID3D11DeviceContext* context = nullptr;
    D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 0, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &device, nullptr, &context);

    // Define compute shader
    const char cs_source[] =
        "RWStructuredBuffer<Particle> particles : register(u0);\n"
        "[numthreads(64,1,1)]\n"
        "void main(uint3 dispatchThreadID : SV_DispatchThreadID) {\n"
        "    Particle p = particles[dispatchThreadID.x];\n"
        "    p.position.x += p.velocity.x;\n"
        "    p.position.y += p.velocity.y;\n"
        "    p.position.z += p.velocity.z;\n"
        "    particles[dispatchThreadID.x] = p;\n"
        "}\0";
    ID3DBlob* cs_blob = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = D3DCompile(cs_source, strlen(cs_source), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, "main", "cs_5_0", 0, 0, &cs_blob, nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        // Handle the error here
        std::cout << "Failed to compile shader: " << hr << "\n";
        return;
    }
    ID3D11ComputeShader* cs = nullptr;
    device->CreateComputeShader(cs_blob->GetBufferPointer(), cs_blob->GetBufferSize(), nullptr, &cs);
    cs_blob->Release();

    // Create input buffer
    Particle particles[1024];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        particles[i].position = XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        particles[i].velocity = XMFLOAT3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
    }
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC input_desc = {};
    input_desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Particle) * 1024;
    input_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    input_desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    input_desc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_STRUCTURED;
    input_desc.StructureByteStride = sizeof(Particle);
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA input_data = {};
    input_data.pSysMem = particles;
    ID3D11Buffer* input_buffer = nullptr;
    device->CreateBuffer(&input_desc, &input_data, &input_buffer);

    // Create output buffer
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC output_desc = {};
    output_desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Particle) * 1024;
    output_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    output_desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS;
    output_desc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_STRUCTURED;
    output_desc.StructureByteStride = sizeof(Particle);
    ID3D11Buffer* output_buffer = nullptr;
    device->CreateBuffer(&output_desc, nullptr, &output_buffer);

    // Set up shader inputs and outputs
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* input_srv = nullptr;
    ID3D11UnorderedAccessView* output_uav = nullptr;
    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srv_desc = {};
    srv_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
    srv_desc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
    srv_desc.Buffer.FirstElement = 0;
    srv_desc.Buffer.NumElements = 1024;
    device->CreateShaderResourceView(input_buffer, &srv_desc, &input_srv);
    D3D11_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW_DESC uav_desc = {};
    uav_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
    uav_desc.ViewDimension = D3D11_UAV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
    uav_desc.Buffer.FirstElement = 0;
    uav_desc.Buffer.NumElements = 1024;
    uav_desc.Buffer.Flags = D3D11_BUFFER_UAV_FLAG_COUNTER;
    device->CreateUnorderedAccessView(output_buffer, &uav_desc, &output_uav);

    // Set shader inputs and outputs
    context->CSSetShader(cs, nullptr, 0);
    context->CSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &input_srv);
    context->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(0, 1, &output_uav, nullptr);

    // Dispatch compute shader
    context->Dispatch(1024 / 64, 1, 1);

    // Read output buffer
    Particle output_particles[1024];
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mapped_resource = {};
    context->Map(output_buffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &mapped_resource);
    memcpy(output_particles, mapped_resource.pData, sizeof(Particle) * 1024);
    context->Unmap(output_buffer, 0);

    // Cleanup
    input_buffer->Release();
    output_buffer->Release();
    input_srv->Release();
    output_uav->Release();
    cs->Release();
    context->Release();
    device->Release();
```

I get the error code 0x80070005 from the `hr` variable returned by the call to `D3DCompile`. I am also running this on visual studio 2021

I originally forgot to include the \0 in the shader code (HLSL), so I added it, but no change. I did a quick google search and discovered that the error code means "Access Denied". Does that mean I have to change something on my computer, or is it a code problem? I have full admin access on my computer (windows 10) if that helps.

Comment: *I originally forgot to include the \0 in the shader code* - you don't need to do `"...\0"`, the zero is included in any string literal`"..."`.

Comment: Oh whoops, sorry still pretty new to this

Comment: You did not indicate which function call is returning the "Access Denied" error. Also, there are a lot of return values that you are not checking for failure at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your shader uses `Particle` which is neither included nor defined in the HLSL code.

Comment: So would just added the struct to the HLSL code fix that, or is there more to it?

Comment: Start with adding the struct. You should also specify what function call exactly returns this error. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would also help others to help you.

Comment: It's generally a lot easier to debug shaders building them directly from ``.hlsl`` files with ``FXC.EXE``. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dtools/dx-graphics-tools-fxc-using). Visual Studio also has built-in support for [building shaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-part1).